# How to not obtain any row if there is nothing in both tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

On our site I have the profile.php file generating user-specific profiles from database using following SQL query.

```
select
    u.username,
    u.email,
    u.access,
    date_format(u.registerdate, '%e. %c. %Y') as `registered`,
    date_format('00-00-0000 00:00', '%e. %c. %Y') as `last_visited`,
    count(p.id) as `posts`
from
    users u,
    posts p
where
    u.username = ? AND p.post_creator = u.id
;
```

And below I test if user exists with all of his data, using `mysql_num_rows()` function (please avoid comments about using deprecated PHP's MYSQL extension, I am only improving friend's old code).

The problem comes here, because if I type unexisting user-name to the `WHERE` clause (replacing the question mark), instead of returning expected empty result-set MySQL database returns me one row, with most fields filled with `NULL`s, `last_visit` containing expected `0. 0. 0000` and `posts` containing `0` (zero).
It is pretty, but I don't want to test some unique fields (like `u.username`) whether they aren't empty/`NULL` or not, in my PHP script, because that is very dirty way to check.

I still wanted to obtain empty result-set. I tried `JOIN`, then `WHERE (...) AND u.id is not null` but both didn't work (no behavior change). Then I tried `HAVING u.id is not null` and after adding a column to `SELECT (...)` expression, it worked.
But I had known that `HAVING` clause is intended for filtering result-set after select. And I am asking you:

Is there some cleaner way to do this? Mention of filtering rows this way while `SELECT`. (Or is this good practice? I haven't found pretty answer on my question.)

Comment: Your aggregate function `COUNT(p.id)` will ever return a value of zero or higher. So you will ever got one row at minimum and can't use mysql_num_rows() to check wether the user exists or not.

Comment: Thanks @VMai — I forgot. That means that there is no other way but `HAVING u.id is not null`?

Comment: such a GROUP BY clause with HAVING could do the trick.

Comment: @VMai Please, can you slightly draw how you mentioned it?

Comment: add `GROUP BY u.uid HAVING u.id IS NOT NULL` after your WHERE clause.

Comment: Yeah, it works. But if I use only `GROUP BY` without `HAVING` works so, and adding `u.id` to `SELECT` column references `HAVING u.id is not null` works too, without GROUP BY. Why is this so miscellanous?

Comment: Those queries will run only with MySQL. If you use an aggregate function like `COUNT`, you've got to GROUP BY every non aggregate column in standard sql. And with HAVING is the same, see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) *The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is arising because of some strange behavior of `group by`.  An aggregation query with no rows *always* returns one row, even when all rows are filtered out.  An aggregation query with a `group by` can return 0 rows.  So, I think you just want to add a `group by`:

```
select u.username, u.email, u.access,
       date_format(u.registerdate, '%e. %c. %Y') as `registered`,
       date_format('00-00-0000 00:00', '%e. %c. %Y') as `last_visited`,
       count(p.id) as `posts`
from users u join
     posts p
     on p.post_creator = u.id
where u.username = ?
group by u.username;
```

Note that I also changed the query to use explicit `join` syntax with the join condition in the `on` clause.  Explicit joins are more powerful than implicit joins.